# Declaring pointers in headers ? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

First of all, let me tell you that I'm super noob with C++. So, sorry if i'm asking something stupid, but i'm completely stuck.

I'm trying to port a little game engine i wrote in AS3 to C++ and I have started with the core Game class. It has to store the levels, to update and manage them, so I think pointers is the way to go.

The header looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "Level.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Level *level;
    Level *nextLevel;
    Game(void);
    virtual ~Game(void);
    virtual void begin();
    virtual void onEveryFrame();
private:
    void changeLevel();
};
```

And the compiler throws me two errors for every pointer declaration :

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

So, what am I doing wrong ? The error description doesn't looks too descriptive to me.

(I'm using VS Express 2012)

**EDIT :**

Sorry guys! Looks like is a **circular dependency** problem. Nothing to do with the pointers actually.

The "Level.h" was something like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class Level
{
public:
    Game *game;
    Level(void);
    virtual ~Level(void);
    virtual void begin();
    virtual void onEveryFrame();
};
```

Sorry guys, noob error. :(

Comment: What does `Level.h` look like?  On a side note, since you're just learning C++, let me tell you that pointers (especially raw pointers like you have here) are seldom "the way to go".

Comment: Don't use raw pointers if you just began with C++.

Comment: +1 for fast learning :-))). @Bartek I disagree with "don't use raw pointers" advice - it's C/C++ - you must learn! Yes, they are dangerous but its very expensive to avoid them in low level languages like C/C++. Should I avoid index `[]` and `new` operator in C++ too? ;-).

Comment: @Bartek But your warning is quite useful to take additional care on pointers.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko How exactly expensive is raw pointer compared to `unique_ptr`? Also C **and** C++ are two different languages; in C pointers are used all over the code and it's the main reason it shouldn't be used in anything that doesn't require absolutely maximum speed. If you mean `op[]` for, for example, `vector`, then yes, prefer iterators to integer indices. `new` is OTOH often unnecessary, after move semantics were introduced and you can keep the speed when passing as value/returning by value.

Comment: @Bartek OK, `unique_ptr` provides actually not so much - just life time limits but `move()` is not free. Count 2 additional calls to its constructor / destructor. For cases where you just need to allocate object and provide guarantee it is deleted in non performance critical or resource constrained code it's perfect. OK, ths is usually not my case :-). OK, in general you definitely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `Level.h` is definitely expected to declare `Level` type (most probably class) but it has some issue which prevents `Level` type to be declared. Check it or publish here.
2. Your `Game.h` header actually doesn't need to know about `Level` type details. If your `Level.h` header is expected to declare `Level` as class you are enough to have `class Level;` declaration in your `Game.h` header. This is enough to use pointers. Of course if you try to manipulate objects of type `Level` you need to see its interface. So you definitely need `Level.h` inclusion in module implementing `Game` class.

**Update**:
I have noticed your edit, circular dependency are resolved exactly with declarations I mentioned in [2]. In addition they lower project garbage and build complexity. This is widely used technique in C / C++ (in C it is usually struct or something similar). The idea is to declare just 'it is type' everywhere you don't need actual object size or detailed interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roman. Very helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular dependency, so whichever header file you include one of the two classes is going to need a forward declaration of the other when the compiler hasn't yet had any information about what type "Level" or "Game" is going to be.

The solution is a simple forward delcaration.

```
#pragma once
#include "Level.h"

class Level;

class Game
{
public:
    Level *level;
    Level *nextLevel;
    Game(void);
    virtual ~Game(void);
    virtual void begin();
    virtual void onEveryFrame();
private:
    void changeLevel();
};
```

and do the reciprocal forward-declaration of Game in the Level header.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler doesn't recognize the type `Level`. Maybe an include/typo error?